# Automatize transfer of rows from a mysql db to another closed server securely

Tags: mysql, security, automation

We have our private server, running our Intranet with mysql.

We want to send some of the rows on another server also running mysql, in (almost) real time but here's the catch... the distant server has no API and doesn't accept any connections from outside. All we have to my knowledge, is access to phpmyadmin on the foreign server, and a ftp space. This space can execute server side scripting languages.

What's the best practice in this case?

I have an idea but it feels clunky. Running a script on our server, that sends rows into a csv or txt file into the distant ftp, and have a second scripts in the foreign server that inserts the file in the db, then empties the file.

We have thought of allowing distant connection from the server to our intranet... but it feels like a big security flaw. Maybe you could confirm that...

Comment: Do you have control over both systems?

Comment: I have total control of the source system only, I have access to a ftp space and phpmyadmin on the distant server. I can't do system modifications like installing a program, rebooting, this kinds of things.

Comment: So you just have a shared webspace on the remote server?

Comment: Exactly, it's a common shared remote space.

Comment: Then your idea with uploading and running an import script (are cron jobs supported?) isn't that bad. Or you just rent a small VM (for like $10/month), and do what ever you want (including replication).

Comment: I think cron jobs are included. Yes VM could work...might check this. thank you for your input.

Comment: Don't forget to write an answer when you've got a solution :-)